# xunit why basic inlinedata are not provided?

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I don't understand why my test returns :

> System.InvalidOperationException : The test method expected 1 parameter value, but 0 parameter values were provided. Exception doesn't have a stacktrace

while my very basic test matches with examples found here and there :

```
 [Theory]
    [InlineData("‘")]
    [InlineData("«")]
    [InlineData("£")]
    [InlineData("€")]
    [InlineData("à")]
    [InlineData("é")]
    [InlineData("î")]
    [InlineData("ï")]
    public void IsAsciiComplient_Fail(string c)
    {
        //Act
        bool actual = c.IsAsciiComplient();

        //Test
        Assert.False(actual);
    }
```

I've also tried with char instead of string with no luck.

As there is no stack trace, how can i fixe it please?
Any clue on what is going wrong?

Comment: ok this was a bug with resharper, i've updated resharper to v2017.3.1 , problem solved

Answer (score 5):

Rebuild whole solution and try again.

Answer (score 1):

this was a bug with resharper, i updated resharper to v2017.3.1 then the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when I had two tests with the same name, one being a Theory and one being a Fact. Giving the Theory a unique name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with Visual Studio 17.3 Test Explorer (but not ReSharper) and xUnit when I had subclassed xUnit's `TheoryAttribute` because I wanted to provide [custom skipping logic](https://danielwertheim.se/xunit-dynamically-skipping-tests-for-different-test-environments/). Reverting to using `[Theory]` instead of my subclass resolved it for me. Thanks to [B. Collins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65151105/979493) for giving me an idea of what might be wrong.